# How to keep blank in excel cell if the cell value is #N/A

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to write a VBA to sum two column cell and writing to another column, If the sum is #N/A then leave that cell as blank instead of writing #N/A in that cell.

please see below What I was written to get the sum.

```
StartCellLtr = Split(Cells(1, 29).Address, "$")(1)
        ActiveSheet.Range(StartCellLtr & "3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(VLOOKUP(RC" & ColNumber_Item & ",[Validate.xlsb]Data!R1C1:R" & Count & "C16,{6,7},0))"
        ActiveSheet.Range(StartCellLtr & "3").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(StartCellLtr & "3:" & StartCellLtr & lastrow)
```

Comment: Add an outer `IFERROR`.

Comment: `"=IFERROR(SUM(VLOOKUP(RC" & ColNumber_Item & ",[Validate.xlsb]Data!R1C1:R" & Count & "C16,{6,7},0)),"""")"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question... add an outer `IFERROR`:

```
"=IFERROR(SUM(VLOOKUP(RC" & ColNumber_Item & ",[Validate.xlsb]Data!R1C1:R" & Count & "C16,{6,7},0)),"""")"
```